# Couldn't infer template argument in my attempt to make "map" function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to make a "map" function in C++, which takes a function and a container and returns that container but with elements of type, returned by the function, those elements should be the results of applying the function to elements of container argument.

So for example we should be able to do this:

```
map([](int i){return float(i + 1);}, vector<int> {1, 2, 3});  // vector<float> {2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
```

This is my attempt to implement it but looks like I don't fully understand template programming:
http://ideone.com/zMYCVw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template <
    typename FunctionT,
    template <typename> class ContainerT,
    typename ElemT,
    class FunctionResultT = typename std::result_of<FunctionT>
>
ContainerT<FunctionResultT> map(
    FunctionT func,
    const ContainerT<ElemT>& container
){
    ContainerT<FunctionResultT> resultContainer;
    for (const auto& elem : container){
        resultContainer.push_back(func(elem));
    }
    return resultContainer;
}


template <typename T>
T increaseByOne(const T& number){
    return number + 1;
}

template <typename T>
std::string numberToString(const T& number){
    return std::to_string(number);
}


int main(){
    const auto theList = std::list<float> {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

    for (const auto& ele : map(numberToString, map(increaseByOne, theList))){
        std::cout << ele << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This is the compiler's error:

```
file.cpp:39:48: error: no matching function for call to 'map'
    for (const auto& ele : map(numberToString, map(increaseByOne, theList))){
                                           ^~~
file.cpp:13:29: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'FunctionT'
ContainerT<FunctionResultT> map(
                        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: It seems you like making your life complicated...

Comment: Not every container has `push_back` method

Comment: Ok, I want to make this at least for those containers which do have it. If there is a way to make it more general, that's even better.

Comment: And the problem here is not whether every container has push_back or not. I don't understand how to write map's declaration correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found several things that were causing problems. Here's a list of what I found:

- Function templates represent an infinite overload set. The type of the function needs to be known when you are passing it in as an argument. That means it template arguments need to be explicitly specified. That is, these need to be changed:

  ```
  map(numberToString, map(increaseByOne, theList)
  //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

  To this:

  ```
  map(numberToString<float>, map(increaseByOne<float>, theList)
  //                ^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^
  ```
- `std::list` takes more than one template argument. The rest are defaulted. When you defined your template argument as:

  ```
  template<typename> class ContainerT,
  ```

  it meant `ContainerT` could only accept a single template argument. When the compiler sees that you're trying to deduce this type from an instance of `std::list` it sees that that the number of template arguments don't match. Then type deduction fails. C++11 has variadic parameter packs, you can use them to make `ContainerT` accept any number of template arguments:

  ```
  template<typename...> class ContainerT,
  ```
- And lastly, you didn't provide the `type` for `FunctionResultT`. You can do this here:

  ```
  class FunctionResultT = typename std::result_of<FunctionT>::type
  //                                                        ^^^^^^
  ```

  But note that this will fail because `std::result_of` is a template that only provides a `::type` member if its template argument is a functor. This basically means that if it is a class that has an overloaded `operator()` member function.

  Instead of using `std::result_of`, you can have `FunctionResultT` defaulted to the type of the function call. Like this:

  ```
  class FunctionResultT = decltype(std::declval<FunctionT>()(std::declval<ElemT>()));
  ```

Now this is the result of the changes I made:

```
template <
    typename FunctionT,
    template <typename...> class ContainerT,
    typename ElemT,
    class FunctionResultT = decltype(std::declval<FunctionT>()(std::declval<ElemT>()))
>
```

Comment: +1 you can use `result_of` for the last one if you include the argument types as well `class FunctionResultT = typename std::result_of<FunctionT(ElemT)>::type`

Comment: You should give the full definition of `map`, because the correct way to do the variadaic template args may not be obvious.

Comment: I really like Praetorian's improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class OutputContainer, class InputContainer, typename Fn>
OutputContainer map(Fn fn, InputContainer input_container){
    OutputContainer output;
    for(auto&i:input_container)
        output.push_back(fn(i));
    return output;
}
```

Comment: the problem here is that the return type cannot be deduced, but needs to be specified at compile time (`auto foo=map(func,bar);` won't compile, you need `auto foo=map<appropriate_type>(func,bar);`).

Comment: This may be advantage - output container may have different type than input container.